# Coroutine Async Question Returns Different Result

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I was doing this

```
val jobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<Response<AvailabilityResponse>>>()
while (something) {
    jobs.add(
        async {
           // some API call
        }
    )
}
val availabilities = jobs.awaitAll().map {
   // format some response
}.flattern()
```

However, when I log the result of the jobs, it doesn't seem like all the results are being collected. Am I doing this wrong? (Sometimes it gave me more data, sometimes it gave me less data) Please take a look! thanks so much!

Let me add some addition info, if I do the following way, then the data I got is always consistant. which is so weird. Unfortunaly, I can't use this way since I don't know how many jobs I need to create.

```
val job1 = async {...}
val job2 = async {...}
val job3 = async {...}
val availabilities = listOf(job1, job2, job3).awaitAll().onEach(...).flattern()
```

Comment: This code doesn't really show a problem. Could you elaborate on what "more data" and "less data" means, preferably with some more code?

Comment: thanks for taking a look. what I mean "more data" means sometimes I will get more data from the API response. So it is not consistant.

Comment: So some of the responses have too much or too little data when you're generating the jobs in a loop?

Comment: yep, it only happens in the loop. the other way works fine.

Comment: That's quite strange, there should be no difference between starting the jobs in a loop vs starting them one by one. Maybe it's something unrelated like the API returns a different amount of data randomly?

Comment: not really, the API is fine, if it returns randomly, then the second way would return random data too.

Comment: Yes, so something else is the problem. The coroutine part looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just came back to answer my question after a bunch of research.

so the right way to do it is that

```
val jobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<Response<AvailabilityResponse>>>()
while (something) {
   coroutineScope {
    jobs.add(
          async {
             // some API call
          }
    )
  }
}
val availabilities = jobs.awaitAll().map {
   // format some response
}.flattern()
```

and the reason is that asyc {} will use Dispatchers.Default to run it if no dispatcher is given. and one way to fix is to make it surrounded with coroutineScope